# I am writing a JDBC program using JSP. I am not getting an expected output

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, jdbc

When user enters wrong password i need to show error and then load login.html using request dispatcher but i am getting login form without any error.
[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pfJ3.png)

When user enters correct password it is showing correct output but it is showing login.jsp in the url rather than welcome.jsp
[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9poG.png)

This is my login.html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>Login Here</h1>
        <form action="login.jsp" method="post">
            <div>
                <label for="username">Username: </label>
                <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="password">Password: </label>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="Login">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my login.jsp code:

```
<%@page import="java.util.*, java.io.*, java.sql.*, javax.sql.*, java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter, java.time.LocalDateTime"%>
<html>
    <body>
        <%
            String username = request.getParameter("username");
            String password = request.getParameter("password");
            try 
            {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test", "root", "saiakhil");
                Statement st = conn.createStatement();
                String sql = "select * from myusers where username = '" + username + "' and password = '" + password + "'";
                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
                if (rs.next() == false)
                {
                    out.println("<h2>Invalid Username or Password!</h2>");
                    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("login.html");
                    rd.include(request, response);
                }
                else
                {
                    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("welcome.jsp");
                    rd.forward(request, response);
                }
                st.close();
                conn.close();
            }
            catch (SQLException se) 
            {
                out.println(se);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                out.println(e);
            }
        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my welcome.jsp code:

```
<%@page import="java.util.*, java.io.*, java.sql.*, javax.sql.*, java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter, java.time.LocalDateTime"%>
<html>
    <body>
        <%
            String username = request.getParameter("username");
            out.println("<h2>Logged in successfully</h2>");
            DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");  
            LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
            out.println("<h3>Welcome " + username +"</h3>");
            out.println(dtf.format(now)); 
        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should use a redirect on the client to change the URL in the browser. But looking at your code, this is not the way to go forward, you should thing about using a WebMVC framework to separate the logic from the output.

Comment: Since JSP/Servlet is a MVC framework, just refactor `login.jsp` in a servlet and `login.html` into a JSP page. See [How to avoid Java code in JSP files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3177733/11748454). When you supply the wrong password, the `<h2>` tag is printed **before** the contents of `login.html` and the browser does its best to display this invalid HTML.